# which loop would i use for this situation

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to write a program that can take 5 different angles, and 4 velocities and use them in an equation to find the a temperature. Is there a way to make a loop so that it will easily enter all the combinations of the velocity and angles into the equation? My knowledge of C++ is very basic since I am a beginner and the only way I can think of is very long and probably wrong.

```
((v/b)^2) * sin(alpha) = kr * Ts^4 + Uc * Ts - q

v = {16000, 16500, 17000, 17500}

alpha = {10, 25, 40, 55, 70}
```

**edit** : by the way the other variables have been given, i just needed help find how to deal with the loop/array. thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: [help starting a program C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931560/help-starting-a-program-c)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to only use those velocities and angles, you could write a nested loop that only selects those discrete values.

```
for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500) {
    for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15) {
        /* Execute your formula with velocity and angle variables */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to operate on every angle-velocity pairing and that the angles & velocities are stored in two arrays:

```
for (int i=0; i<5 /* number of angles */; i++) {
 for (int j=0; j<4 /* number of velocities */; j++) {
  /* Do whatever it is you're doing with angles[i] and velocities[j] */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You require a nested loop if I understand correctly. You require something like this:

```
for each angle
    for each velocity
          calcuate temperature
```

You can nuse either `for` or the `while` loop to achieve this. IMHO, `for` loops looks better in this case.